# understanding lagrange theorem of numberr theorem

Tags: number-theory

In number theory, Lagrange's theorem is a statement named after Joseph-Louis Lagrange about how frequently a polynomial over the integers may evaluate to a multiple of a fixed prime. More precisely, it states that if p is a prime number and f ( x ) ∈ Z [ x ]   is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then either:

```
every coefficient of f(x) is divisible by p, or
f(x) ≡ 0 (mod p) has at most deg f(x) incongruent solutions.
```

Solutions are "incongruent" if they do not differ by a multiple of p. If the modulus is not prime, then it is possible for there to be more than deg f(x) solutions. can anyone help me understand this by one simple quadratic equation or cubic equation example?

Comment: Please give some context. Do you know modular arithmetic or congruences, or any ring or field theory? Note that $\bmod 8\!:\ x^2 -1\,$ has $4$ roots $\,x\equiv \pm1,\pm 3\ \ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Consider the congruence equation

$$x^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{15} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note that $15$ doesn't divide every coefficient, i.e., $1$, $0$ and $-1$. Also, you have the solutions $x = 1, 4, 11 \text{ and } 14$, i.e., $4$ incongruent solutions for a degree $2$ polynomial.

As you asked, this shows that if $p$ is not prime, with it being $p = 15 = 3 \times 5$ in my example, then the number of incongruent solutions may be more than the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: I don't think he used $p$ denoting an arbitrary natural number.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Actually, the OP's question ends with "If the modulus is not prime, then it is possible for there to be more than deg f(x) solutions. can anyone help me understand this by one simple quadratic equation or cubic equation example?" In this case, the modulus is $p$. I believe my answer is what the OP is asking for, i.e., a simple example which shows what they're asking about.

Comment: You're right, I misread it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may be easily seen as a polynomial problem over the [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) [$\mathbb{Z}_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n), $p$ prime. If you had used $p=16$ with $f(x)= x^2,\,x = 0,4,8,12$ are all your solutions.

Just like the reals, a polynomial with degree $n$ has at most $n$ reals roots. This follows from the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials. By the same construction, a polynomial over *any* field with degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots. By roots over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ we mean equivalence classes given by $\operatorname{mod}p$; which are exactly the number of incongruent solutions (different classes of congruent solutions). You can read more about this [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392d/Chap7.pdf).

Comment: OP, if either of the responses fits your question, please consider upvoting and marking them as the answer.